# How to disable mobile version of website?

Tags: java, web, mobile, bootstrap-4

I've website that is not full responsive for mobile devices. So is there any possibility to set my app that always loads like desktop version when someone visit it from mobile device? I used Java, Bootstrap, HTML, CSS, JavaScript, jQuery, spring, hibernate for developing this site.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">` from your html file.